# Вывод документа на странице

Tags: битрикс, php, html

Привет!

Есть страница, содержащая в себе блок с документом, но никак не могу понять, как его подключить к другим документам. В php коде все чисто, ничего нет. Подскажите, куда копать? Весь код перелопатил, ничего не нашел.

Вкратце: есть страница http://www.verbnyi.ru/bron/m2/bron.php, слева есть блок "Реестр свободных квартир", нужно его скопировать и вставить на другую страницу. Но понятия не имею, где он находится, кто его инклюдит и где вообще этот код находится. Прошу помощи!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Зайдите в администраторскую панель, откройте раздел настройки-сайты-список сайтов, найдите свой сайт. Откройте его и посмотрите, какой шаблон используется. Потом откройте шаблоны сайтов и перейдите к редактированию того шаблона, который используется для сайта. Найдите там условие или компонент, который показывается в левом контейнере. По идее, там будет либо путь к файлу, либо вообще сам код данного блока.

Comment: @binliz спасибо! Получилось.

Answer (score 0):

> кто его инклюдит и где вообще этот код находится

Включите режим правки. Если этот код во включаемой области, то когда Вы наведете курсор мыши на кнопку "Редактировать", увидите путь к файлу. Если это какой-то компонент, аналогичным образом сможете увидеть какой.

[image: включаемая область битрикс]

Comment: @baduga в том то и дело, что при включении редактирования этот элемент пропадает.